# Null check on decimal crystal reports using CDBL({value})

Tags: vb.net, null, crystal-reports, formula

I am using a decimal value in a formula which gives error when there is no data.
I tried using CDBL({value}) i.e. create a formula for value=CDBL({value}) .
The use {@value} in the formula. This used to take care of null values. But now  keep getting error IF NOT ISNULL({@Value}) THEN ' A number, or currency amount is required here. Details: errorKind
Any suggestions on how to fix this please

Comment: You've been a member for 4+ years; asked 5 previous questions and gotten 6 answers.  None are accepted and of course never ever voted.  Time to read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: try this " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252279/crystal-reports-formula-field-if-isnulldecimal-then-0-00-does-not-work-co

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this and see if I get any sort of indication that it worked.. maybe even a correct answer indication :)

You cant have mixed field types returned in Crystal. If one part of the IF statement returns a numeric type then the rest has to be numeric type. If you post your entire formula I (or someone else who is willing to give up valuable time) can show you how it needs to look.

Comment: IF {@Count}=0 THEN 0
ELSE
{Table_Result.Value}/{@Count}

Comment: @Count is a formula field with : CDBL({Table_Result.Count})

Comment: It gives me the following error: 'IF {@Count}=0 THEN 0 ' A number, or currency amount is required here. when Count is null i.e. dataset is empty. Using CDBL on fields and using the formula field in other formulas used to work earlier. I don't know what changed but it gives error too recently!